# Issues with installing cryptography in python 3.8.0 with custom openssl

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, cryptography, paramiko

I am involved in a project to compile python 3.8 and a certain set of libraries to be deployed in a mixture of RHEL6 & RHEL7 machines.  Further, due to the differences of RHEL6 & 7(primarily certain libraries found in /lib64), if I were to compile this in a RHEL7 box, my python install doesn't work in the RHEL6 box but the other way around works.  So I am now trying to compile this stuff in RHEL6 machine, package it and deploy it across the board.

Please note the box I am compiling Python 3.8 and the libraries are air gapped machines, so I just transfer the source from a different machine to the build machine.

One of the first problems I ran into was, Python3.8 complained about an old version of ssl libraries, I got around that problem using the steps outlined in the link below

https://jameskiefer.com/posts/installing-python-3.7-on-debian-8

This is where I run into an issue.  I used the openssl that I compiled earlier to build Python 3.8 and used that to compile cryptography against, paying attention to the link below.

https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#static-wheels

Cryptography gets installed just fine, but it still keeps pointing to the native libssl rather than the new updated one that I compiled.

In the section where the wheel is generated, I turned on debug mode and I noticed these commands.

```
  running build_ext
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_padding.c'
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_constant_time.c'
  generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_openssl.c'
  building '_openssl' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/apps/ops/python3/include/python3.8 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build/temp.li
nux-x86_64-3.8/_openssl.o -Wconversion -Wno-error=sign-conversion
```

It looks like the _openssl.o that's being generated just uses the OS native libraries, although I see my switches showing up properly shortly after.

```
  gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build/temp.linux
-x86_64-3.8/_openssl.o -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so
  building '_constant_time' extension
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/apps/ops/python3/include/python3.8 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_constant_time.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build/t
emp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_constant_time.o
  gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build/temp.linux
-x86_64-3.8/_constant_time.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_constant_time.abi3.so
  building '_padding' extension
  gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/apps/ops/python3/include/python3.8 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/_padding.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build/temp.li
nux-x86_64-3.8/_padding.o
  gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib -Wl,-rpath,/apps/ops/python3/openssl/lib build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/build/temp.linux
-x86_64-3.8/_padding.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_padding.abi3.so
```

Please look at the output below.  I am at a total loss here to figure this out, or is this just not feasible and I have to look at a different solution.

```
(env) [user1@devhost wheelhouse]$ python -c "from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend;print('Loaded: ' + backend.openssl_version_text());print('Linked Against: '
 + backend._ffi.string(backend._lib.OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT).decode('ascii'))"
/home/user1/tmp/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py:159: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: OpenSSL version 1.0.1 is no longer supported by the Open
SSL project, please upgrade. The next version of cryptography will drop support for it.
  warnings.warn(
Loaded: OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Linked Against: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

(env) [user1@devhost wheels]$ python -c 'import ssl; print (ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'
OpenSSL 1.0.2t  10 Sep 2019
```

Comment: Have you read [Using your own OpenSSL on Linux](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/#using-your-own-openssl-on-linux). It seems you need to **recompile Python** with your new `OpenSSL` version as `Cryptography` doesn't want to link with a different version. Perhaps `Cryptography` asks `Python` where the `OpenSSL` is.

Comment: I have compiled my python with my local version of Openssl and it is linked just fine.  I just am  having trouble coaxing cryptography to point to the same local version of Openssl python3 is aware of.  I am fairly certain this has to do with cffi but I don't know that module well so I am struggling with it.